# Join based on date difference

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, date, join, pyspark

I have the following 2 dataframes:

| client | Date |
| --- | --- |
| A | 202001 |
| A | 202002 |
| A | 202105 |
| B | 202203 |
| B | 202001 |
| C | 202205 |
| C | 202207 |
| C | 202206 |

| client | Date |
| --- | --- |
| A | 202004 |
| B | 202205 |

(real dataframes contain more dates and clients)

I now want to add a column to dataframe 1 that evaluates to `1` or `0` based on the following conditions:
`1` if client is is in the second dataframe AND the date is maximum 4 months apart.
`0` otherwise

Expected output:

| client | Date | condition |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 202001 | 1 |
| A | 202002 | 1 |
| A | 202105 | 0 |
| B | 202203 | 1 |
| B | 202001 | 0 |
| C | 202205 | 0 |
| C | 202205 | 0 |
| C | 202206 | 0 |

Comment: If you had A 202004 and A 202005 in df1, would they be 1 or 0?

Comment: Yes, they would also evaluate to 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could first, in the df2, create a [`sequence`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#sequence) of dates and [`explode`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.explode.html#pyspark.sql.functions.explode) it. Then join.

Dataframes:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df1 = spark.createDataFrame(
    [('A', 202001),
     ('A', 202002),
     ('A', 202105),
     ('B', 202203),
     ('B', 202001),
     ('C', 202205),
     ('C', 202205),
     ('C', 202206)],
    ['client', 'Date'])
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(
    [('A', 202004),
     ('B', 202205)],
    ['client', 'Date'])
```

Script:

```py
df2 = df2.withColumn('Date', F.to_date('Date', 'yyyyMM'))
df2 = df2.withColumn('Date', F.explode(F.expr("sequence(add_months(Date, -4), add_months(Date, 4), interval 1 month)")))
df2 = df2.select('client', F.date_format('Date', 'yyyyMM').alias('Date'), F.lit(1).alias('condition'))

df_result = df1.join(df2, ['client', 'Date'], 'left') \
               .fillna(0, 'condition')

df_result.show()
# +------+------+---------+
# |client|  Date|condition|
# +------+------+---------+
# |     A|202002|        1|
# |     A|202001|        1|
# |     B|202203|        1|
# |     A|202105|        0|
# |     C|202206|        0|
# |     C|202205|        0|
# |     C|202205|        0|
# |     B|202001|        0|
# +------+------+---------+
```